# Flutter - response.body returning HTML instead of json

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to return the json from the api, but html arrives even adding the header specifying application/json.
As the image shows, the api works perfectly in Postman.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the `.body` property of the response [as outlined here](https://pub.dev/packages/http#using)?

Comment: what <HTML> response did you get? it may caused by something error from the header

Comment: Yes, i used response.body

Comment: @pmatatias I added the image

Comment: @Felipe Please can you provide your response code (200, 400, 500 and etc.)  and do you need to use token for your API?

Comment: its probably error while handling an object. did you `jsonDecode(response.body)` before convert into an object?

Comment: and also, please provide more code on your Future function

Comment: @PavelMaltsev 200. The API is open

Comment: http://cep.la/avenida+paulista it's not a json api, I just called it. Use this site to check it https://reqbin.com/. I also recommend you check your request in VS Code with some extensions.

Comment: @PavelMaltsev https://restninja.io/   Here it works

Comment: @PavelMaltsev. https://restninja.io/share/b3949f138446901cc131b04a7acc5983643e43d0/0

Comment: @PavelMaltsev https://reqbin.com/khed4s5o

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `response.body` to get the json data

```
String Json = response.body;
```

Comment: Yes, i used response.body